# Formatar nomes de arquivos usando Expressão Regular

Tags: regex

Estou tentando renomear alguns arquivos usando Expressão Regular, mas estou empacado em um formato especifico. Tenho arquivos de vídeo nesse formato:

> Yu.Yu.Hakusho Ep.001 - A Morte

Preciso formatar usando regex para:

> Yu.Yu.Hakusho.S01E01 - A Morte

Tentei usando `([^ ]+)*.(\w{0,2}).([0-9]+)*.(.*.)` para capturar somente aquilo que preciso e formatar, como pode ser visto logo abaixo:

```
$texto = "Yu.Yu.Hakusho Ep.001 - A Morte";
$regex = "/([^ ]+)*.(\w{0,2}).([0-9]+)(.*.)/";
preg_match($regex,$texto,$m);   

echo $m[1].".S01E".$m[3].$m[4];
```

E a saida é

> Yu.Yu.Hakusho.S01E001 - A Morte

não estou sabendo como deixar a sequencia `001` apenas com os dois últimos digitos.

Como faço essa substituição com regex?(não posso usar replace, preciso fazer apenas com ER mesmo)

> Obs.: usei o php como exemplo, mas preciso necessáriamente aplicar uma
>   regex, independente de linguagem, como pode ser visto aqui nesse link:
>   https://regex101.com/r/dC3aN4/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criei outro *pattern* de regex do zero, porque achei o seu um pouco "desorganizado."

*Pattern*: `(.*?) .*?\d?(\d{2}).*?(\w.*)`

Substituição: `\1.S01E\2 - \3`

Se preferir usar o mesmo *pattern* que já estava usando, eu fiz uma versão modificada dele: `([^ ]+)* (\w{0,2})\.\d?(\d{1,2})*.(.*.)`" A substituição continua a mesma.

Comment: Se não for abusar da sua boa vontade, poderia explicar como essa regex funciona? Tenho outros padroes pra aplicar, talvez entendendo esse filtro eu possa apenas adapta-lo pras outras situações :)

Comment: Se você realmente quer entender como regex funciona recomendo procurar um livro ou curso online. (Esse é o primeiro resultado no Google e parece bom: http://aprenda.vidageek.net/aprenda/regex) Mas explicando a estratégia do regex que eu fiz aí em cima, ele faz o seguinte: Obtém tudo até um espaço e coloca no \1, obtém tudo até um número qualquer, obtém dois números e coloca no \2, obtém tudo até alguma letra, obtém da letra até o final da string e coloca no \3.

Comment: Sendo que na parte que ele "coloca dois números no \2" pode **ou não** ter um número antes, por causa do `?` que está após o `\d`.

Comment: Entendi agora, eu só não estava entendendo bem o funcionamento desse  `?`. Vou usar ambas para referencia, obrigado :)

Comment: Bem, creio que esse exemplo só funcionará até o episódio 99, quando chegar em 101 ele vai salvar como S01E01

Comment: Alterando um pouco a pattern feita pelo nossa amigo @DanielDutra para uma que funcione até o 999° episódio : /(.*?) .*?Ep.?(\d{2,3}).*?(\w.*)/

Comment: Realmente, a minha solução só funcionará corretamente até o episódio 99, mas, de acordo com a pergunta, ele só quer exibir dois números após o "E". Usando o seu regex o problema inicial da pergunta volta a acontecer, a saída fica com 3 zeros após o "E": Yu.Yu.Hakusho.S01E001 - A Morte.